# What's the real problem of using both negative and positive grounded equipment at the same rack/location?

Tags: short-circuit

It's always recommended not to use negative and positive grounded equipment in the same rack/location, as this connection can cause a short circuit.
In this example, both devices have their own rectifier, where one uses -48 VDC (positive grounded) and the other +48 VDC (negative grounded).
In this condition a short circuit could happen if I use a shielded Ethernet cable to connect them. I think that even with a unshielded Ethernet cable this problem can happen.
My question is: why could this short circuit happen in this situation?
I can't explain why this condition could happen, even though I know it's a real fact.
See the picture below for more info

Additional information

- These items of equipment are telecommunication radios used to transmit/receive data
- These rectifiers convert AC (110/220) in DC (-/+48)

[image: Connection illustration]

Comment: You need to explain what devices these are and why would there be a short circuit. First of all, if all the equipment have their metal chassis connected to same ground, there is no potential difference between device metal parts such as Ethernet connector. Also Ethernet interface data pins are galvanically isolated with a transformer so as per the standard there could be 1000 volts between the devices and it would work fine, and with unshielded Ethernet cable there could even be 1000V difference between the device metal parts. So you need to tell us why it is a fact as we can't see a short.

Comment: As it's just a hypothetical situation I didn't mention any equipment model.

Comment: But you asked what is the real problem. If the scenario is hypothectical, what is the real problem then?

Comment: I have several sites with different equipment models in each of them, and all of these solution use +48 VDC or -48 VDC.
I reached that "short-circuit conclusion" based on some forum posts and also from some friends who had used these equipment in a similar way.
I'll try to use them this way and see if they work normally or if something burns out rsrsrs

Answer (score 0):

The issue is if you connect -48V telco kit to a +48V supply (or vice versa).

You might think that as long as the equipment has floating internals, then all is fine. Just get the polarity right, and that's it.

However, it is now common practice to use Mesh Bonding Network to minimize EMC (instead of the older Isolated Bonding Network), with the grounded supply line connected to chassis earth inside the equipment via a grounding link.

For +48V kit this is from the -ve terminal to ground.  For -48V kit this is from the +ve terminal to ground.  Mix and match, and you suddenly find you equipment is grounding your supply via a low impedance link.

In my experience that is why equipment with different grounding expectations is kept separate.

I've seen this as an issue most often not with +48V kit in a -48V central office, but with +24V kit (common in mobile sites) installed in a -48V central office, powered via a non-isolated 48V to 24V converter...

Comment: They should have used a 48V to 72V converter for the 24V equipment,